# Trying to evaluate a function within a function numerically

Tags: r, integration, numerical-integration

Here is my code:

```
L=function(t){
  n0=n2=1
  n1=1.5151
  A=function(theta){
    n0/(sqrt(n1^2-n2^2*(sin(theta))^2))*n2^2*sin(theta)*cos(theta)/(n1^2-n0*sqrt(n1^2-n2^2*(sin(theta))^2))
  }
  B=function(theta){
    -50/(cos(theta))^2*n1*n2*sin(theta)/(n1^2-n0*sqrt(n1^2-n2^2*(sin(theta))^2))
  }
  F=function(theta0){
    exp(integrate(A(theta),lower=0,upper=theta0))
  }

  1/(F(t))*(50+integrate(F(theta)*B(theta),lower=0,upper=t))
}
```

I am trying to evaluate a integral within a integral. So I placed some dummy variables in the function, which apparently you are now allowed to do so. Can anyone help me to fix that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `integrate` function expects a function as its first argument, so you would just pass something like `A` or `function(x) F(x)*B(x)`. The error message "Error in A(theta) : object 'theta' not found" should have been a hint about this issue.

Secondly, the `integrate` function returns a list of type `integrate`, so you appear to need to `value` element of that list. Putting it all together:

```
L=function(t){
  n0=n2=1
  n1=1.5151
  A=function(theta){
    n0/(sqrt(n1^2-n2^2*(sin(theta))^2))*n2^2*sin(theta)*cos(theta)/(n1^2-n0*sqrt(n1^2-n2^2*(sin(theta))^2))
  }
  B=function(theta){
    -50/(cos(theta))^2*n1*n2*sin(theta)/(n1^2-n0*sqrt(n1^2-n2^2*(sin(theta))^2))
  }
  F=function(theta0){
    exp(integrate(A,lower=0,upper=theta0)$value)
  }

  1/(F(t))*(50+integrate(function(x) F(x)*B(x),lower=0,upper=t)$value)
}
L(1)
# [1] -19.33926
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here. First `exp(integrate(A(theta),lower=0,upper=theta0))` does not work because `integrate` returns a list. You need to access the value of the integral with `$value`.

Second, the first argument to integrate must be a function, not a function value, so `integrate(A(theta),lower=0,upper=theta0)` should be `integrate(A,lower=0,upper=theta0)`, and the same with the integral of `F*B`. Making these changes I get

```
L=function(t){
  n0=n2=1
  n1=1.5151
  B=function(theta){
    -50/(cos(theta))^2*n1*n2*sin(theta)/(n1^2-n0*sqrt(n1^2-n2^2*(sin(theta))^2))
  }
  F=function(theta0){
    A<-function(theta){
      n0/(sqrt(n1^2-n2^2*(sin(theta))^2))*n2^2*sin(theta)*cos(theta)/(n1^2-n0*sqrt(n1^2-n2^2*(sin(theta))^2))
    }
    exp(integrate(A,lower=0,upper=theta0)$value)
  }

  1/(F(t))*(50+integrate(function(x) F(x)*B(x),lower=0,upper=t)$value)
}
```

Which runs, e.g.

```
> L(.5)
[1] 33.4549
```

I'm sure you'll want to reasonability check that answer.

Comment: I think you would want to run `L(10)`, which gives me "Error in exp(integrate(A, lower = 0, upper = theta0)) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function" because you haven't extracted the value with `$value`.

Comment: Thanks, fixed now. L(10) seems to not converge.